# Combobox in dhtmlxgrid on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, combobox, dhtmlx

I have a dhtmlxgrid on my rails app. The grid is working fine but now I need to add a combobox to it and, even after reading all the help on their support foruns and all the documentation, I can't seem to get it working...

Right now I set the column as a combobox, and it's being populated with the current value set on the database. But that column has two possible values. what I need is for the cell to be populated with: first the selected value on the database, but also list the second option if they want to change.

Here's my current code

view.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            var grid = new dhtmlXGridObject("grid_here");
            grid.setImagePath("../assets/dhtmlx/imgs/");
            grid.setHeader("Status");
        grid.attachHeader("#text_filter"); 
        grid.setColTypes("coro");
        grid.setColSorting("str");  
            grid.setInitWidths("60");
        grid.setSkin("dhx_skyblue");
            grid.init();
            grid.load("/data");
            grid.attachEvent("onCheck",doOnCheckBoxSelected);
            dp = new dataProcessor("/dbaction.xml");
            dp.init(grid);

</script>
```

data.xml.builder

```
xml.instruct! :xml, :version=>"1.0" 

xml.tag!("rows") do
    @products.each do |product|
        xml.tag!("row",{ "id" => product.id }) do
            xml.tag!("cell", product.status)
        end
    end
end
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set options on the client side or define them as part of xml data. Check the next article in the dhtmlx's documentation

http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxgrid:initialization_from_xml

For init on client side it look like next

```
grid.getCombo(0).put("1", "First Option")
grid.getCombo(0).put("1", "Second Option")
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that doing that I was going to "overwrite" my databse field! It was very simple to solve this, thanks